# bootstrap 4 navbar-toggler-icon(hamburger) showing two lines instead of three

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm building this navbar with bootstrap 4.

The navbar is working fine, but there is one problem that I have not been able to figure out by my self.

On fold the hamburger icon shows two lines instead of three. I'm not sure why the hamburger is appearing like this, but I'm sure it has something to do with the pseudo elements.

I have spent all morning on figuring out why this is happening. Can someone please take a look at my code and see what I'm doing wrong?

here is a link to a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dadihall/5bd29tf4/3/)

below is a copy of my code

```css
nav {
  padding: 20px 0 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px; }
  
  .navbar {
  padding: 0; }

.navbar-toggler:active,
.navbar-toggler:focus {
  outline: none; }

.navbar-custom .navbar-toggler-icon {
  width: 24px;
  height: 17px;
  background-image: none;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 300ms linear; }

.navbar-custom .navbar-toggler-icon:after,
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggler-icon:before {
  width: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all 300ms linear; }

.navbar-custom .navbar-toggler-icon:after {
  top: 8px; }

.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="true"] .navbar-toggler-icon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg); }

.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="true"] .navbar-toggler-icon:before {
  transform: translateY(8px) rotate(-45deg); }

.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="true"] .navbar-toggler-icon {
  border-color: transparent; }

.nav-link {
  color: #4b4b4b;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: all 200ms linear; }

.nav-item:hover .nav-link {
  color: #3b3b3b; }

.nav-item.active .nav-link {
  color: .nav-item.active .nav-link #c2002d; }

.nav-link {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 0 !important;
  display: inline-block; }

.nav-item:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  content: '';
  background-color: #c2002d;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 200ms linear; }

.nav-item:hover:after {
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1; }

.nav-item.active:hover:after {
  opacity: 0; }

.nav-item {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px;
  transition: all 200ms linear; }

.navbar-brand > img {
  display: block; }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
    <title></title>
  </head>

 <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand-md ">
        <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarDropdown" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarDropdown">
       <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
        <li class="nav-item ">
         <a class="nav-link " href="#" >Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Browse</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Search</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
          </nav>






</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I only see two elements, before and after. That explains why there are only two elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply `border-bottom` to `.navbar-custom .navbar-toggler-icon` to get the third line. check snippet.

```css
nav {
  padding: 20px 0 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px; }
  
  .navbar {
  padding: 0; }

.navbar-toggler:active,
.navbar-toggler:focus {
  outline: none; }

.navbar-custom .navbar-toggler-icon {
  width: 24px;
  height: 17px;
  background-image: none;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 300ms linear; 
    border-bottom: solid 2px #000;
  }

.navbar-custom .navbar-toggler-icon:after,
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggler-icon:before {
  width: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all 300ms linear; }

.navbar-custom .navbar-toggler-icon:after {
  top: 8px; }

.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="true"] .navbar-toggler-icon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg); }

.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="true"] .navbar-toggler-icon:before {
  transform: translateY(8px) rotate(-45deg); }

.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="true"] .navbar-toggler-icon {
  border-color: transparent; }

.nav-link {
  color: #4b4b4b;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: all 200ms linear; }

.nav-item:hover .nav-link {
  color: #3b3b3b; }

.nav-item.active .nav-link {
  color: .nav-item.active .nav-link #c2002d; }

.nav-link {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 0 !important;
  display: inline-block; }

.nav-item:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  content: '';
  background-color: #c2002d;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 200ms linear; }

.nav-item:hover:after {
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1; }

.nav-item.active:hover:after {
  opacity: 0; }

.nav-item {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px;
  transition: all 200ms linear; }

.navbar-brand > img {
  display: block; }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
    <title></title>
  </head>

 <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand-md ">
        <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarDropdown" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarDropdown">
       <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
        <li class="nav-item ">
         <a class="nav-link " href="#" >Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Browse</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Search</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
          </nav>






</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add an extra element in the center, looks better animated :-)

```css
nav {
  padding: 20px 0 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px; }
  
  .navbar {
  padding: 0; }

.navbar-toggler:active,
.navbar-toggler:focus {
  outline: none; }

.navbar-custom .navbar-toggler-icon {
  width: 24px;
  height: 30px;
  background-image: none;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 300ms linear; 
}

.center {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 4px;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-toggler-icon:after,
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggler-icon:before {
  width: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all 300ms linear; }

.navbar-custom .navbar-toggler-icon:after {
  top: 8px; }

.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="true"] .center {
  display: none;
}
.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="true"] .navbar-toggler-icon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg); }

.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="true"] .navbar-toggler-icon:before {
  transform: translateY(8px) rotate(-45deg); }

.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="true"] .navbar-toggler-icon {
  border-color: transparent; }

.nav-link {
  color: #4b4b4b;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: all 200ms linear; }

.nav-item:hover .nav-link {
  color: #3b3b3b; }

.nav-item.active .nav-link {
  color: .nav-item.active .nav-link #c2002d; }

.nav-link {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 0 !important;
  display: inline-block; }

.nav-item:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  content: '';
  background-color: #c2002d;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 200ms linear; }

.nav-item:hover:after {
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1; }

.nav-item.active:hover:after {
  opacity: 0; }

.nav-item {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px;
  transition: all 200ms linear; }

.navbar-brand > img {
  display: block; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
    <title></title>
  </head>

 <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand-md ">
        <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarDropdown" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
            <span class='center'></span>
          </span>
        </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarDropdown">
       <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
        <li class="nav-item ">
         <a class="nav-link " href="#" >Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Browse</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Search</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
          </nav>






</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

couple of modification with your css and html.

```css
nav {
  padding: 20px 0 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-toggler:active,
.navbar-toggler:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-toggler-icon {
  width: 24px;
  height: 17px;
  background-image: none;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 300ms linear;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-toggler-icon:after,
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggler-icon:before {
  width: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all 300ms linear;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-toggler-icon:after {
  top: 8px;
}

.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="true"] .navbar-toggler-icon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="true"] .navbar-toggler-icon:before {
  transform: translateY(8px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="true"] .navbar-toggler-icon {
  border-color: transparent;
}

.nav-link {
  color: #4b4b4b;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}

.nav-item:hover .nav-link {
  color: #3b3b3b;
}

.nav-item.active .nav-link {
  color: .nav-item.active .nav-link #c2002d;
}

.nav-link {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 0 !important;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-item:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  content: '';
  background-color: #c2002d;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}

.nav-item:hover:after {
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav-item.active:hover:after {
  opacity: 0;
}

.nav-item {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}

.navbar-brand>img {
  display: block;
}

.icon-bar {
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #B6B6B6;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin-top: 4px
}

.navbar-toggler {
  border: none;
  background: transparent !important;
}

.navbar-toggler .top-bar {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 10% 10%;
}

.navbar-toggler .middle-bar {
  opacity: 0;
}

.navbar-toggler .bottom-bar {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 10% 90%;
}

.navbar-toggler.collapsed .top-bar {
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.navbar-toggler.collapsed .middle-bar {
  opacity: 1;
}

.navbar-toggler.collapsed .bottom-bar {
  transform: rotate(0);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand-md ">

    <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarDropdown" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
 <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>    
</button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
        <li class="nav-item ">
          <a class="nav-link " href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Browse</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Search</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>






</body>

</html>
```